# How to find last used table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have 2 Identical Oracle Tables (Table1 & Table2). Data insertion in both these tables are truncate and then load. Once the data is inserted to a table, a synonym is applied on it. Also the table to be inserted for next load is found out using

```
SELECT   OBJECT_NAME
     INTO   var1
     FROM   (SELECT   RR.OBJECT_NAME,
                      RANK () OVER (ORDER BY RR.LAST_DDL_TIME ASC) RNK
               FROM   SYS.ALL_OBJECTS RR
              WHERE  RR.OBJECT_NAME IN
                               ('Table1', 'Table2'))
    WHERE   RNK = 1;
```

However I need an alternate technique for this as DDL_TIME for both these tables becomes same if we grant an access role to any user. Please note we cannot alter the table structure

Comment: But why do you have two identical tables???

Comment: Lets say it is a requirement.... :)

Comment: it is a very weird design... but why don't you just write into another table the name of the table to be used by the next iteration, instead of relying on "last ddl time"?

Comment: I can only make procedural changes and no DDLs. I just want a new approach for this using existing objects...

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You have a poor application design.  You are using database metadata for a purpose that it is not intended for.  If you need to keep track of things like the time when a user was granted access to a table, you should keep this information explicitly in another table, either wrapping the access control logic in a stored procedure or using a DDL trigger.

A sign that you have a problem is that `DDL_TIME` isn't doing what you want.  This column is doing what it is documented to do and presumably what the database needs it to do.  The shortcoming is your re-interpretation of it.

Comment: I know It is a bad design, but that is why I am asking help to change this. The constraint is I cannot use DDLs as we have DBAs in our association and going to another team would be a pain...

Comment: @AayushBhatnagar PL/SQL development without ability to modify schema objects is like Java development without ability to modify source code.